# Calling function inside Function Expression in another file always gives undefined errror

Tags: javascript

So, I'm so very newbie in js, and tried to imitate an implementation of function I've seen, but it gave error. And searching and searching I understand neither what's wrong nor what's  different from some example... All of the things below is just a representation of what I'm doing.

I have two js script, `Flower.js` and `Tree.js`.
So, the function I imitated is more or less like this `Flower.js`:

```
var Lily = (function() {

    function petal() {
        //do A
    }
})();
```

And inside `Tree.js` I tried to call `petal` like this:

```
function grow() {
    Lily.petal();
}
```

I put them inside the html like this:

```
<script src="js/Flower.js"></script>
<script src="js/Tree.js"></script>
```

but it gave no result and always gives error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'petal' of undefined

I've tried to change this and that, and the error changes, but no matter what changes I put, it always has `undefined` in error message. What is it the grave mistakes that I've done? Is it in the declaration or calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the petal function could be referred as "a private function of the module Lily"
The following piece of code declare a function that gets immediately called, so the value of Lily is the return value of your function.

If you want Petal to be accessible from Lily you can try something like this :

```
var Lily = (function() {

    return {
        petal : function() {
            console.log('Petal has been called');
        },
        someOtherMethod : function () {
           console.log('someOtherMethod has been called');
        }
    }
 })();
```

Lily.petal();
Lily.someOtherMethod();

Comment: Thank you so very much dude, it worked! ^^ I'm sorry, may I ask again? What if I have more than one function inside `Lily`? Like, I have two functions: `petal` and `bud`... how should I declare them? I've tried something but the way I implemented it makes only the-first-function-to-be-declared could be called...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
var Lily = (function() {

    this.petal = function () {
        //do A
    }
});
```

The extra `()` you had on the end of your function caused it to be executed immediately: in other words, you had created what's known as an IIFE: Immediately Invoking Function Expression. `Lily` was being assigned the value of the return expression from that function, and since you weren't returning anything it was by default being set to `undefined`.

Furthermore, since you hadn't actually specified `petal` as a property of `Lily`, even if `Lily` had been defined, `petal` would have been undefined instead. Since saying `function petal` inside the `Lily` function doesn't add that property to the containing function, you have to specify the property by adding it to `this`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Umm now it changes into this error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"...